# MySQL query optimization in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Can any one re-write this SQL query to perform better?

At present this query takes about 29 seconds to execute in **BlueHost** server while it takes 6 seconds in **HostGator.com** server.

My intention is to delete all records exists in `wp_postmeta` table of **post type='attachment'** and with **meta_key='_mycbgenie_managed_by'**

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE post_id IN 
( SELECT ID FROM wp_posts 
    WHERE post_type = 'attachment' 
    AND post_parent IN 
        ( SELECT ID FROM 
            ( SELECT ID FROM wp_posts a 
                LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON (a.ID = b.post_id) 
                LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (a.ID = mt1.post_id) 
                WHERE post_type = 'product' AND mt1.meta_key = '_mycbgenie_managed_by' 
             ) AS taskstodelete 
        ) 
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Doyou have appropriate indexes? What does explain say about the subquery used for determining the recrds to be deleted? In the 2nd subquery why do you join twice on wp_postmeta table? How does your table structure look like?

Comment: These are WordPress tables, so indexes are pre-built by them. Can you rewrite this SQL as you say that I have used join twice in sub query?

Comment: 1. I'm not going to look up wp tables. Your question, so at the minimum link the table descriptions. 2. You can add indexes to your table. 3. You have to attempt to rewrite the query yourself and tell us what went wrong with that. 3. If you were able to construct the above query, then surely you can eliminate an extra join out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE PM FROM wp_postmeta as PM
INNER JOIN 
    wp_posts as P
    ON PM.post_id=P.ID AND P.post_type='attachment'
INNER JOIN wp_posts as P2
    ON P.post_parent=P2.ID
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS PM2 
    ON P2.ID = PM2.post_id
WHERE P2.post_type = 'product' AND PM2.meta_key = '_mycbgenie_managed_by'
```